# What is the relationship between the different WebSocket protocol versions?

Tags: version, websocket, protocols

I recently learned that there are a plethora of WebSocket protocol specifications (a bunch of them named hixie-*, another bunch of hybi-*, and finally a RFC 6455).

I assumed that hixie- and hybi- were previous drafts, and that the RFC is "the final word" towards all the implementations will eventually converge. However, I was surprised to discover that the RFC is from December 2011, while the latest hybi-* is from February 2012.

Could someone please shed some light? What is the historical development of all those branches and what is the roadmap for the future?

By the way, do those funny names (hixie and hybi) stand for something?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

"Hixie" stems from Ian Hickson ian@hixie.ch .. original proposer/author of the WebSocket protocol.

"Hybi" stems from "hy_pertext bi_directional" .. IETF working group "BiDirectional or Server-Initiated HTTP (Active WG)".

The latest and final RFC is RFC6455. Do implement that.

Hixie-75/76 are deprecated, security flawed, outdated versions that were in use for some time.

Hybi-Draft-N .. where N is .., 10, .., 18 mark revisions of the protocol during the development of the final RFC from draft RFCs.

Everything >= Hybi-10 are only small variants of the final RFC6455.

In short: read and implement https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455 and you will be fine.

Comment: also know that the working group has be rejiggered to discuss extensions to the protocol, so if you are implementing one from scratch it would pay to be aware of where the group is going with the per frame compression, mux extensions and the like.  mux in particular can have a strong effect on how an implementation is written

Comment: A couple clarifications: "security flawed" is a bit overstated. Really, it was a concern about misbehaving HTTP intermediaries, and WebSockets is going above and beyond to avoid confusing them and becoming another attack vector against those broken intermediaries (the existence of them is also theoretical). Current iOS only supports Hixie-76 so if you want to support current iPhone/iPad you also need to support Hixie-76 on the server.

Comment: You a right about iOS: it's the only (major) platform left, on which right now there is no browser with > Hixie-76 (reason being: no 3rd party browser can be installed, builtin browser only speak Hixie-76, and builtin browser has no Flash support, ruling out fallback to WS flash bridge). One more comment: WebKit Nightly supports RFC6455 since begin of March 2012.  So if that makes it into Safari Mobile and older iOS devices get updated, then it might be there in the near future.

Comment: Regarding security flawed: I disagree. You are right, the security flaws were wrt intermediaries, but they were demonstrated by Adam Barth. But it's an involved issue. Anyway: for readers interested, here is background info so you can judge yourself:

 * http://www.ietf.org/mail-archive/web/hybi/current/msg04744.html

 * http://www.adambarth.com/experimental/websocket.pdf